# Scriptrunner/ Copying Project while logged-in as another user

Tags: groovy, jira

I want to use my script, so that it will be executed by someone who is not me, but another user (ServiceUser) in the Jira Instance.
This is my functioning code, but I do not know how to make someone else execute it.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project
import com.atlassian.jira.project.ProjectManager
import com.atlassian.jira.project.AssigneeTypes
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.admin.CopyProject
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.projectroles.ProjectRoleService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.ProjectRole
import com.atlassian.jira.util.SimpleErrorCollection
import com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.ProjectRoleManager
import com.atlassian.jira.project.ProjectManager
import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project
import com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.ProjectRoleActor
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.ProjectCreationData
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.ProjectService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.project.AssigneeTypes
import com.atlassian.jira.project.type.ProjectTypeKey
// the key for the new project
def projectKey = "EXA987"
def projectName = "EXA987"
def log = Logger.getLogger("com.onresolve.jira.groovy.MyScript")
Thread executorThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        def copyProject = new CopyProject()
        def inputs = [
            (CopyProject.FIELD_SOURCE_PROJECT) : "SWTEMP",
            (CopyProject.FIELD_TARGET_PROJECT) : projectKey,
            (CopyProject.FIELD_TARGET_PROJECT_NAME) : projectName,
            (CopyProject.FIELD_COPY_VERSIONS) : false,
            (CopyProject.FIELD_COPY_COMPONENTS) : false,
            (CopyProject.FIELD_COPY_ISSUES) : false,
            (CopyProject.FIELD_COPY_DASH_AND_FILTERS) : false,
        ]
        def errorCollection = copyProject.doValidate(inputs, false)
        if(errorCollection.hasAnyErrors()) {
            log.warn("Couldn't create project: $errorCollection")
        }
        else {
            def util = ComponentAccessor.getUserUtil()
            def adminsGroup = util.getGroupObject("jira-administrators")
            assert adminsGroup // must have jira-administrators group defined
            def admins = util.getAllUsersInGroups([adminsGroup])
            assert admins // must have at least one admin
            ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().setLoggedInUser(util.getUserByName(admins.first().name))
            copyProject.doScript(inputs)
        }
    }
})
executorThread.start()
```

I stumbled upon other codes, using things like

```
def oldLoggedInUser = jiraAuthenticationContext.getLoggedInUser()
        
                jiraAuthenticationContext.setLoggedInUser(serviceUser)
              
                jiraAuthenticationContext.setLoggedInUser(oldLoggedInUser)
```

but it was not succesful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have used following solution to change user during script execution:

```
def authContext = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext();
def currentUser = authContext.getLoggedInUser();
def superuser=ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByKey("ANOTHER_USER_ACCOUNT")
authContext.setLoggedInUser(superuser);
// < do the needed work>
authContext.setLoggedInUser(currentUser);
```

I had first issues as my used another account had not needed Jira access rights (and I got funny "user must be logged in" errors)